# How can I delete text that is NOT in quotes or parentheses?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, sed, perl

Input:

```
19. "foo foo" (bar bar) (19) raboof
"foo foo" raboof
```

Expected output:

```
"foo foo" (bar bar) (19)
"foo foo"
```

As you can see, I would like to keep the double quotes and parentheses.

Everything that is not between double quotes or parentheses should be removed.

Comment: You've changed the task. That's not fair.

Comment: My sincere apologies A.B. I was not aware that a space would cause an issue

Comment: Sorry do you want to *remove* everything not between double-quotes or parenthesis? If so it's very different from extracting the content of the parenthesis

Comment: The previous one extracted specific text in parentheses, and kept everything else that wasn't inside parentheses.
Now I would want to extract specific text in parentheses, and keep only the text in quotes.

But now the easiest option is to use heemayl's solution first, and then run the solution to the initial question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `python`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import re, sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split()
        for i in parts:
            if re.search(r'^[("].*[)"]$', i):
                print i,
        print '\n'.lstrip()
```

**Output:**

```
"foo" (bar) (19) 
"foo"
```

- Every line is read and parts separated by spaces are saved into a list called `parts`
- Then by using `re` module's `search` function we found the parts that begin with either `"` or `(` and end with either `"` or `)`.

**How to run:**

Save the script as e.g. `script.py`. Now you can run it in two ways:

- Make it executable by `chmod u+x /path/to/script.py` and run it as `/path/to/script.py /path/to/file.txt` i.e. input the file `file.txt` as the first argument. If both script and file are in the same directory, then from that directory `./script.py file.txt`
- You can run it without making it executable, run it as `python2 script.py file.txt`.

**Answer to the edited question:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import re, sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        print ''.join(re.findall(r'(?:(?<=\s)["(].*[")](?=\s|$)|(?<=^)["(].*[")](?=\s|$))', line))
```

**Output:**

```
"foo foo" (bar bar) (19)
"foo foo"
```

Comment: Thank you heemayl. How can I make the python script into a file and then run it like so: `/path/to/thisscript < file`

Comment: @user264974: Check my edits..

Comment: I also noticed that the script doesn't work as I expected if the text between the quotes and parentheses contain a space, but that is my fault for not being specific. I edited my question

Comment: @user264974: Check my new edits..

Answer (score 5):

**New version** (spaces allowed between `()` or `""`):

Try the below `perl` command (credits: @[steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver))

```
perl -ne 'printf "%s\n", join(" " , $_ =~ /["(].*?[)"]/g)'
```

---

**Initial version** (no spaces between `()` or `""`)

You can try the following `perl` oneliner:

```
$ perl -ne '@a=split(/\s+/, $_); for (@a) {print "$_ " if /[("].*?[)"]/ };print"\n"'  file
```

Comment: Short, and it works +1 ;)

Comment: He has changed the task. That is unfair.

Comment: This worked really great for the initial question I had, which involved a single word inside the parentheses and quotes. However after further investigation, I found that it did not work with multiple words in side quotes/parentheses. My sincere apologies, I didn't mean any harm

Comment: @user264974: No problem, glad that you find your answer.

Comment: @SylvainPineau I think the trick for the second case is *not* to split the input before searching for regex matches, e.g. `perl -ne 'printf "%s\n", join(" " , $_ =~ /["(].*?[)"]/g)'`

Answer (score 4):

Another python option:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
match = lambda ch1, ch2, w: all([w.startswith(ch1), w.endswith(ch2)])

for l in open(sys.argv[1]).read().splitlines():
    matches = [w for w in l.split() if any([match("(", ")", w), match('"', '"', w)])]
    print((" ").join(matches))
```

- Copy the script into an empty file, save the script as `filter.py`
- Run it with the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/filter.py <file>
  ```

#### On the edited version of the question:

If we *assume* there is a *closing* character on every *opening* character: `'('` and `'"'` (we should assume that, since otherwise either the file would be incorrect or the question would have to mention a more complex set of rules in case of "nested" parentheses or quotes), the code below should do the job as well:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
chunks = lambda l: [l[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(l), 2)]

for l in open(sys.argv[1]).read().splitlines():
    words = chunks([i for i in range(len(l)) if l[i] in ['(', ')', '"']])
    print((" ").join([l[w[0]:w[1]+1] for w in words]))
```

It lists characters in the list: `['(', ')', '"']`, makes chunks of two out of the found matches and prints what is in the range of each couple:

```
19. "foo" (bar bar) (blub blub blub blub) (19) raboof
"foo" raboof
```

will then output:

```
"foo" (bar bar) (blub blub blub blub) (19)
"foo"
```

The use is exactly like the first script.

More or other "triggers" can be easily added by adding both sides (start- and end character of the string or section to "keep") in the list:

```
['(', ')', '"']
```

in the line:

```
words = chunks([i for i in range(len(l)) if l[i] in ['(', ')', '"']])
```

Comment: I noticed that the script doesn't work as I expected if the text between the quotes and parentheses contain a space, but that is my fault for not being specific. I edited my question

Comment: @user264974 No problem, but you're giving us a new challenge :)

Comment: Great edit, thank you, it now works with what I intended it to use it for with spaces included. I saved it as a second option to heemayl's. I love how we can get different results through different methods!

Answer (score 4):

If you (or someone else with a similar problem who reads this) don't need to preserve the newlines, the following would work:

```sh
grep -Eo '"[^"]*"|\([^)]*\)'
```

For input

```
19. "foo foo" (bar bar) (19) raboof
"foo foo" raboof
```

it yields output

```
"foo foo"
(bar bar)
(19)
"foo foo"
```

If you need newlines, you can use some tricks, e.g. this:

```
sed 's/$/\$/' \
| grep -Eo '"[^"]*"|\([^)]*\)|\$$' \
| tr '\n$' ' \n' \
| sed 's/^ //'
```

The first `sed` adds a `$` to the end of every line. (You could use any character for this.) The second is almost the same `grep` as above, but now also matches `$` at the end of a line, so it matches every end of line. The `tr` turns newlines into spaces, and dollars into newlines. But since the output before that `tr` had `$` followed by newline, the output after will have newline followed by space. The final `sed` gets rid of those spaces.

Answer (score 3):

As `perl` script:

```
$filename=$ARGV[0];
if (open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)) {
  while (my $match = <$fh>) {
    while ($match =~ /((\(.*?[^)]\))|(".*?"))/g) {
      print "$1 ";
    }
    print "\n"
  }
}
```

Or as `perl` one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'while (/((\(.*?[^)]\))|(".*?"))/g) {print "$1 ";} print "\n"' file
```

**Output**

```
"foo foo" (bar bar) (19) 
"foo foo"
```

---

---

That was the [original task](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/616991/1):

> **Input:**
>
> 19. "foo" (bar) (19)
>
> raboof "foo" raboof
>
> **Expected output:**
>
> "foo" (bar) (19)
>
> "foo"

Using `perl`:

```perl
perl -pe '@elements=( split (/\s/) ); 
    for $element (@elements) {
        if ($element!~/^"|\(/ and $element!~/"|\($/) {
            s/$element//
        }
        s/^\s+//;
        s/\s+$/\n/
    };' file
```

or as one-liner:

```
perl -pe '@elements=( split (/\s/) ); for $element (@elements) { if ($element!~/^"|\(/ and $element!~/"|\($/) { s/$element// } s/^\s+//; s/\s+$/\n/ };' file
```

**Output:**

```
"foo" (bar) (19)
"foo"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `perl`:

```
$ perl -nle 'print join " ", $_ =~ /".*?"|\(.*?\)/g' file
"foo foo" (bar bar) (19)
"foo foo"
```

Answer (score 2):

Below simple python code will do this job.

```
import re
with open('file') as f:
    reg = re.compile(r'"[^"]*"|\([^)]*\)')
    for line in f:
        print(' '.join(reg.findall(line)))
```

And another one through Perl which uses only regex,

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?:"[^"]*"|\([^)]*\))(*SKIP)(*F)|\S//g;s/^\h+|\h+$|(\h)+/\1/g' file
"foo foo" (bar bar) (19)
"foo foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP would be:

```
if (preg_match_all('/"(?:[^"\\\\]+|\\\\.)+"|\\([^)]+\\)/', $input, $matches)) {
  echo implode(' ', $matches[0]);
}
```

This also correctly handles escaped characters inside quoted strings (eg `"Test \"string\""` is treated as one string.